# Is there way to locate the points in a hexagon in a picture using Python?

Tags: python

I am working a project related to locate the score card in a hexagon scale, but in a jpg format.
And my thought is to transfer it to a score and store in a dataset format.

Is there any way to handle it using Python?

Example for the hexagon scale:

[image]

I am trying to use following

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

but cannot run for contours attribute.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to handle this in Python. If you are currently not able to handle this, it is because you have made a mistake, not because Python is not capable of doing this.

Comment: Please share more, as I was new to python, sorry about that…